# What time zone should I set Magento for?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, timezone

I live in KY US (Eastern Time UTC-05:00).

My customers are mostly from the US.

My server is in Phoenix AZ (Mountain Time UTC-07:00).

If I want to try to equal out the time as best as possible for US customers, would setting the Locale setting in Magento to something like Chicago be best or to my KY time or the server time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the timezone which is set in the server. If you don't do this, you have wrong calculations all over the place:
salesrules, catalog price rules, order with wrong date, etc.

Comment: Thanks I'll do it like that because I've been having some issues. I don't think I've ever set it to the server time.

Comment: How can your answer be tested. It didn't fix magento logging me off (my little ongoing project). I just want to  be sure I have the time correctly.

Comment: Make an order, check the shown order date in backend, should be correct. If it isn't, either the server time is wrong, the server timezone or php/magento timezone setting is wrong.

Comment: Or both is wrong, but makes the end time correct :D

Comment: It shows me in admin the I placed the order at the same time as the server time. Is that the correct time?

Comment: I noticed when working with coupons that if I placed an order around 10pm - 11pm and tried to use the coupon it wasn't any good because the day the coupon started, supposedly the same day the order was placed, wasn't good yet. Because the the day was a different in one time zone than another. So if you place an order at 11pm on say the 28th Magento might say the order was on the 29th. So the coupon isn't good until the 29th. If the customer buys immediately then the coupon isn't good. Shouldn't it give the correct time for the customer?

Comment: Freejoy if this is the time you want to work with (coupons, finance, bookkeeping, ...) then yes, if no, then no ;-)